# Root password stopped working

Tags: macos, password, login, root

I used to be able to [enable “root” user](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528) and log in under it.
(I know this is not recommended but let's just assume there is an actual reason for doing so.)

I just repeated the instructions, set another root password and logged out of my account.

However, logging in with `root` user and the password I typed doesn't seem to work.
The login screen just shakes as if the password is incorrect.

I already tried setting it to a different one, then to an empty string—nothing works.
What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have followed [these instructions](http://www.macosliontips.com/tips/enable-root-account-in-mac-os-x-lion.html) and still can't get it to let you in as root, I would recommend trying out the instructions in [this support discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16200978#16200978) to get it working.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: thanks Nathan, I'll try to fix up this answer and I'll avoid only linking in the future.